# Setting and element's opacity and then animating it - all with JS

Tags: javascript

I am working on a new site that is using page transitions. The old content fades away and the new content fades in - at least that's what should happen.

When the new content is loaded, I use JS to set it's opacity: 0

`this.newContainer.style.opacity = 0;`

Then, I add a new class so I can use CSS transitions

`this.newContainer.classList.add("animate-in");`

This is the CSS for the .animate-in

```
.wrapper.animate-in {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

However, this doesn't work. The code doesn't animate the opacity from 0 to 1. Instead, it is animating backwards, from 1 to 0. It seems like the classList.add doesn't hear the previous line of code.

Anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT

OK, so I learned that using the JS style.opacity will completely override any opacity CSS rules. This is my problem. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css animation and remove code--> this.newContainer.style.opacity = 0;

```
 .wrapper.animate-in {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
        animation: animate-in01 1s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
  }

    @keyframes animate-in01{
        0% {
           opacity: 0;
        }        
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not my problem. I know how to use CSS animation. My problem is that a JS declaration is wiping out my CSS set opacity.

Comment: try remove this.newContainer.style.opacity = 0; and add opacity: 0; in .wrapper.animate-in like this .wrapper.animate-in { opacity: 1; transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out; animation: animate-in01 3s; animation-iteration-count: 1; } @keyframes animate-in01 { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }

Comment: Ok this seems to be working better. The new content fades in properly. But in my JS, I am using a transitionend eventlistener to trigger something when the CSS animation is complete. This eventlistener isn't picking up the ending of the keyframe CSS animation.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I replaced the transitionend listener with an animationend listener.